# compondentDidMount argument is undefined and cannot execute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to execute two functions in my component in componentDidMount. The first is getArticle which loads one article into the state (and this works fine). The second is getAuthor, which uses the authorId key from the previously fetched article object and fetches the author and puts it into the state but it says that the argument for the getAuthor function is undefined, even if I add a conditional. I can see the authorId in the state. What is the right way to fetch my author data?

Article.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getArticle } from "../actions/articleActions";
import { getAuthor } from "../actions/authorActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Article extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getArticle(this.props.match.params.id);
      //^ this works and the Article is in my state

    if (this.props.article.article) {
      this.props.getAuthor(this.props.article.article.authorId);
    }
    //^ this does not work. authorId id still undefined

  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.article.loading) {
      return <p>Loading!</p>;
    }

    const data = this.props.article.article;

    function checkAndRenderBody() {
      if (typeof data === "undefined") {
        return;
      } else {
        return data.body.split("\r").map((c) => {
          return <p> {c} </p>;
        });
      }
    }
    function checkAndRenderName() {
      if (typeof data === "undefined") {
        return;
      } else {
        return data.name;
      }
    }
    function checkAndRenderAuthor() {
      if (typeof data === "undefined") {
        return;
      } else {
        return data.author;
      }
    }
    function checkAndRenderID() {
      if (typeof data === "undefined") {
        return;
      } else {
        return data._id;
      }
    }

    return (
      <Container>
        <p>{checkAndRenderName()}</p>
        <p>{checkAndRenderAuthor()}</p>
        <p>{checkAndRenderBody()}</p>
        <p>{checkAndRenderID()}</p>
        <br />

        <Link to="/">Back to index</Link>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

Article.propTypes = {
  getArticle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getAuthor: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  article: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  article: state.article,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getArticle, getAuthor })(Article);
```

authorReducer.js

```
import { GET_AUTHOR, AUTHORS_LOADING } from "../actions/types";

const intialState = {
  author: [],
  loading: false,
};

export default function (state = intialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_AUTHOR:
      return {
        ...state,

        author: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case AUTHORS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

actions/types.js

```
export const GET_ARTICLES = "GET_ARTICLES";
export const GET_ARTICLE = "GET_ARTICLE";
export const ADD_ARTICLE = "ADD_ARTICLES";
export const DELETE_ARTICLE = "DELETE_ARTICLES";
export const ARTICLES_LOADING = "ARTICLES_LOADING";

export const GET_AUTHOR = "GET_AUTHOR";
export const AUTHORS_LOADING = "AUTHORS_LOADING";
```

authorActions.js

```
import axios from "axios";

import { GET_AUTHOR, AUTHORS_LOADING } from "./types";

export const getAuthor = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setAuthorsLoading());
  axios.get(`/api/authors/${id}`).then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_AUTHOR,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  );
};

export const setAuthorsLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: AUTHORS_LOADING,
  };
};
```

Comment: is you check the articleId value in console.log within that If loop?

Comment: in the conditional, this.props.article.article is never defined, so anything in the conditional is not executed. If I don't have the conditional, an undefined error gets thrown

Comment: yes @Robert It should thrown undefined if there is no conditional over there. Here, articleId is undefined within that loop, Is it right what i understood?

Comment: Yes it is undefined. It would normally be stored in this.props.article.article.authorId but this.props.article.article is not defined.

Comment: if possible can you reproduce this in stackblitz.com. It may easy to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your `mapStateToProps` you are assigning `state.article` to the prop `article`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    article: state.article,
});
```

So if your data is structured as expected, you *should* be able to access it at `this.props.article`, not `this.props.article.article`:

```
if (this.props.article) {
    this.props.getAuthor(this.props.article.authorId);
}
```

Comment: Yes, however, inside componentDidMount, this.props.article is an empty list. Under render(), however, this.props.article is the article that I want. How can I execute getAuthor after this.props.article has the data that I want?

Comment: You need to use `componentDidUpdate` and check for when `this.props.article.authorId` is available, as when the AJAX call for `this.props.getArticle` is returned it should update your props and will call `componentDidUpdate` with the updated prop.

Comment: ^^ this comment helped tremendously. Thanks